# Can't get file uploads to work from android to ASP.NET server

Tags: java, android, asp.net, http, http-headers

I've been stuck on this for a week now and I can't seem to get anywhere. I'm trying to upload a photo from myphone to an API biult with ASP.NET but I keep getting the error: "`Error writing MIME multipart body part to output stream.`".
This is my java code, I'm using to upload the photo as a java.io.file object:

```
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) this.url.openConnection();

urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization","bearer " + User.GetToken());

String boundary = "----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW";

urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);

dataOutputStream.writeBytes("--" + boundary + "\r\n");
dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"FormData\";
filename=\"filename.jpg\"; \r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n");
dataOutputStream.writeBytes("\r\n\r\n");

dataOutputStream.write(fileToByteArray(file)); // file = java.io.File

dataOutputStream.writeBytes("\r\n");
dataOutputStream.writeBytes("--" + boundary + "--\r\n\r\n");

dataOutputStream.flush();
dataOutputStream.close();
```

The upload works fine when using Postman so I'm pretty sure the error is not on the server side.

Comment: `DataOutputStream` for such things is always a bad choice ... `DataOutputStream` is for java primitives ... HTTP protocol knows nothing about java's prmitives ...

Comment: What should I use instead?

Comment: It was the just off-topic comment... The problem is prolly NetworkOnMainThredException